# didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken not called consistently

Tags: ios, push-notification

Yesterday there was a loop in a testing environment that caused many push notifications to be sent out to a specific device. Since then, when I try to register a device sending token, when the app is first installed the didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken does not seem to be called at all. It does however ask for push notifications to be enabled or disabled upon installation. It also shows up in the notification center. I tried the following.

1. Resetting settings
2. Restarting phone
3. Set phone clock ahead 3 days.
4. tried on multiple devices.

It does work consistently using the production build which uses a different target, but not the QA build. using Xcode Version 7.3 iOS 9.3.1. My question is why would didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken not be called, with other provisioning profile it is called. The code is the same. Can apple block a device from registering? I have didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError implemented with no errors in either case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing changed and the following day everything works perfectly. It MUST be related to apple putting some sort of temporary block since many push notifications went out.

Comment: Exactly Apple blocks notification after some time if they find unsual

Answer (score 0):

Have you implemented `application:didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:` ?

The registration might be failing and when you haven't implemented the above method, you are getting nowhere.

Comment: I have that implemented, it does not get called ether. No errors of any kind

Answer (score 0):

Did you checked it in the Xcode IDE Target -> Capabilities -> Push notification